# Issues SSHing between two Amazon EC2 instances of same region in different availability zones

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I’m using two Amazon EC2 classic micro instances (A & B) of same region in different availability zones. I’m trying to connect the instances using SSH. Every time while I’m trying to connect, it is showing the error:

> connect to host 172.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out.

I have given the SSH access in security groups to the instances (A & B).

I’m able to connect the instances (A & B) from different servers using SSH.

I have tried the following commands on both the instances(A & B):

**Instance A:**

- `ssh -i path-to-key.pem user@private-ip-of-B`
- `ssh -i path-to-key.pem user@public-ip-of-B`

**Instance B:**

- `ssh -i path-to-key.pem user@private-ip-of-A`
- `ssh -i path-to-key.pem user@public-ip-of-A`

Please let me know where I’m going wrong.

Comment: Can you ping between hosts?

Answer (score 0):

`ping` may not work if ICMP is disabled (typically it is). Please make sure that

1. Your security groups are configured correctly
2. The **PUBLIC KEY** you're using is in both target user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. You either have the same UID already created on the instances. If not, you need to connect as ec2-user with a command similar to this

   ssh -i path-to-key.pem ***ec2-user***@private-ip-of-A